# Print All Files in Folder and SubFolders

Tags: terminal

I had 5 folders each with a couple of files (2-3).

I wanted to print all of them in one shot. I found ways to do it in Linux but I couldn't get them to work here.

The two alternatives I found for Linux were:

> find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t
>
> find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | cut -d\  -f2-

How do I accomplish this on a Mac?

I'd prefer not downloading any package for this and to accomplish this solely through terminal.

Comment: What happens if you try the commands in Terminal?

Comment: -t is not recongnized and printf not defined respectively.

Comment: It's `find` complaining about `-t`, not `ls` :-)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get the same result is

```
find . -type f
```

which basically is identical to

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
```

Comment: The `-t` in your `ls` command is superfluous.  `find` does not do any time-based ordering; and, as only one file at a time is passed to xargs, sorting the one file at a time by the file's date (as `-t` would normally do) is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX requires specifying the path argument for `find` (like `find .` instead of `find`) and `-printf` is a GNU extension.

List regular files sorted by modification date:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -f'%m %N' {} + | sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f2-
zsh -o dotglob -c 'printf %s\\n **/*(.om)'
```

List regular files:

```
find . -type f
zsh -o dotglob -c 'printf %s\\n **/*(.)'
```

List all files (including directories):

```
find .
shopt -s globstar dotglob; printf %s\\n ** # bash 4.0 or later
brew install tree; tree -a . # -a includes files that start with .
mdfind 'kMDItemFSInvisible=1||kMDItemFSInvisible=0' -onlyin .
```

List only directories:

```
find . -type d
shopt -s globstar dotglob; printf %s\\n **/ # bash 4.0 or later
tree -ad .
```